# Error handling using 'Either' inside a recursive function

Tags: haskell, error-handling, binary-tree

Assuming a binary search tree, I would like to return an error in case we are trying to insert an element that is already there.  Is there a way to make this work?

```
data BST2 a = EmptyBST2 | Node2 a (BST2 a) (BST2 a)  deriving Show

insert2 :: a -> Either b (BST2 a) -> Either b (BST2 a)
insert2 elem (Right EmptyBST2) = Right (Node2 elem EmptyBST2 EmptyBST2)
insert2 elem (Right (Node2 root left right))
  | (elem == root) = Left "Error: Element already exist."
  | (elem < root) = (Node2 root (insert2 elem left) right)
  | otherwise = (Node2 root left (insert2 elem right))
```

Note: I am new to Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is simpler to solve using helper functions:

```
insert2 :: (Ord a) => a -> BST2 a -> Either String (BST2 a)
insert2 newVal tree
  | contains newVal tree = Left "Error:  element already in tree"
  | otherwise = Right $ insert newVal tree
```

Now you need `contains` and `insert`:

```
contains :: (Ord a) => a -> BST2 a -> Bool
contains .... implementation .... -- checks whether a BST2 contains an element

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> BST2 a -> BST2 a
insert .... implementation .... -- inserts an element if not already there,
                                --   otherwise returns original tree
```

Alternatively, instead of `Either String (BST2 a)`, you could use one of [Haskell's many other approaches](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors) to errors.

Answer (score 6):

@Andre just tried to provide a minimal fix for your code. An idiomatic way to implement your error handling task in Haskell is to use the `Error` monad. The main reason for that is a possibity to reuse `liftM2` library function to implement `combine`. `throwError` and `return` can be replaced by `Left` and `Right`, but the generic functions explain the purpose of your code more clearly.

```
module Err where

import Control.Monad (liftM2)
import Control.Monad.Error (throwError)

data BST2 a = EmptyBST2 | Node2 a (BST2 a) (BST2 a)  deriving Show

combine root = liftM2 (Node2 root)

insert2 :: (Ord a) => a -> BST2 a -> Either String (BST2 a)
insert2 elem EmptyBST2 = return $ Node2 elem EmptyBST2 EmptyBST2
insert2 elem (Node2 root left right)
  | (elem == root) = throwError "insert2 error: Element already exists."
  | (elem < root) = combine root (insert2 elem left) (return right)
  | otherwise = combine root (return left) (insert2 elem right)
```

Note that `combine` can be shorter: `combine = liftM2 . Node2` or longer: `combine root left right = liftM2 (Node2 root) left right`. Use the style you understand best.

Also some comments regarding the errors @Andre fixed:

- `insert2` was not polymorphic in error type - it always returned a `String` in case of failure. So he used  `String` in the type declaration instead of `b`.
- Unlike lists, ordered collections cannot store any type - only types which can be compared (ordered) can be put into a tree. So he added `Ord a =>` constraint on tree value type to indicate that `<` and `==` must be implemented for the type.
- `insert2` returns `Either`. You tried to pass `Left` or `Right` to `Node2` and `Node2 root (Left foo) right` fails because it expects `Node2 a` but `Either String (Node2 a)` is provided.

Finally, one more reason to use `throwError` and `return` is that the function becomes generic:

```
insert2 :: (Ord a, MonadError String m) => a -> BST2 a -> m (BST2 a)
```

and you can use it with instances of `MonadError` other than `Either`, but you need to add `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` pragma at the top of your source file before the `module` declaration.

Comment: thanks for the improvement. (BTW, I deliberately did not mention monads.)

Comment: My policy is to provide two answers for wrong code: a minimal fix and a better implementation. A better implementation alone has low educational value so my answer is not an improvement but an additional clue.

Comment: Looks like the type could be more general: `insert2 :: (Ord a, MonadError String m) => a -> BST2 a -> m (BST2 a)`?

Comment: 1) Not in Haskell98 2) We wanted to avoid scary monads as much as possible 3) Yes

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick solution (not necessarily simple):

```
data BST2 a = EmptyBST2 | Node2 a (BST2 a) (BST2 a)  deriving Show

combine :: a -> Either b (BST2 a) -> Either b (BST2 a) -> Either b (BST2 a)
combine a (Left b) _ = Left b
combine a _ (Left b) = Left b
combine a (Right left_subtree) (Right right_subtree) = Right (Node2 a left_subtree right_subtree)

insert2 :: (Ord a) => a -> Either String (BST2 a) -> Either String (BST2 a)
insert2 elem (Right EmptyBST2) = Right (Node2 elem EmptyBST2 EmptyBST2)
insert2 elem (Right (Node2 root left right))
  | (elem == root) = Left "Error: Element already exist."
  | (elem < root) = combine root (insert2 elem (Right left)) (Right right)
  | otherwise = combine root (Right left) (insert2 elem (Right right))

-- test data
t1 = EmptyBST2
t2 = Node2 17 t1 t1
t3 = Node2 42 t2 t1
t4 = insert2 11 (Right t3)
t5 = insert2 17 (Right t3)
```

Comment: There is really no reason for insert2's second argument to be of type `Either String (BST2 a)`, `BST2 a` would suffice!

Comment: `combine` is just `liftM2 . Node2`